# QT Terminal Example not sending data

Tags: c++, qt, qtserialport

Qt ["Terminal Example"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-terminal-example.html) is not working as expected with RS232.

I am using this as a boilerplate for my serial GUI application but cannot get it to send data to my device. Using the same settings in PUTTY I get a perfect output. I have narrowed it down to the issue that it will only send a single message and then no more. Is there some loop in there? I've already put debug statements all over to check unknown actions with no luck.

I checked what functions are outputting but I cannot see anywhere that it closes the port.

I also thought that maybe it was just me not sending the \r command but even this did nothing. I simply send the first message and then it does nothing.

I have tried sending it manually, with commands like these:

```
m_serial->write("command"); 
m_serial->write("command\r");
```

I have also tried following a solution here: [How to make QSerialPort from Qt5.13.1 work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58020663/how-to-make-qserialport-from-qt5-13-1-work)

I tried to update to the newest version and the maintenance tool did not find repository so I just did a clean install with 5.12.5 and same problem persists.

In my image, the first set of open-close is the terminal example. The second set is Putty working. I am definitely connecting because the error checking and serial port info I get from Qt is correct. [image: AccessPort Output]

**EDIT**

My port settings are:

- Baud: 9600
- Data bits: 8
- Stop Bits: 1
- Parity: None
- Flow Control: None

Qt Version: 5.13.1, 5.12.5

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58020663/how-to-make-qserialport-from-qt5-13-1-work

Comment: Good catch, that sure seems like it, what's the fix though? How do update to a new version?

Comment: Read the answer, there indicate several workaround.

Comment: What you indicate in your edition is incorrect, if you read more carefully you will see that it indicates: **Solution: For now you have the options to downgrade to 5.13.0, wait for Qt 5.13.2 or Fix the Qt 5.13.1 qserialport yourself ...** and clearly you have used the second option

Comment: Yes, but the manual fix does not work. I should clarify that sorry.

Comment: That you do not know how to implement it does not imply that it does not work. But beyond that point that answer offers 3 possible solutions, not just the patch, so just one of them works for you to make the answer valid.

Comment: This may not be the same issue, it seems similar but a clean install of an older version has not resolved it either.