# How can I fix bug camera in Qt5.13.1?

Tags: qt, camera, qml

I wanna adjust exposure related settings in my camera. 
For example I try to use function `camera.searchAndLock()` but it doesn't work.

I tried to run camera example of Qt, but for the following code I have always `Unlocked` status.

```
switch (m_camera->lockStatus()) {
    case QCamera::Searching:
    case QCamera::Locked:
        m_camera->unlock();
        break;
    case QCamera::Unlocked:
        m_camera->searchAndLock();
    }
```

I write the following QML codes, but the following code always return `unlocking focus`.

```
if (camera.lockStatus == Camera.Unlocked) {
    camera.searchAndLock();
    console.log("searching focus...")                                
   }                                 
   else {                           
        camera.unlock();                        
        console.log("unlocking focus...")                            
     }
```

I want to change exposure related settings in my camera by the following codes, but all of them do not work:

```
camera.searchAndLock()    
camera.exposure.exposureCompensation = value
camera.exposure.spotMeteringPoint.x=value
camera.exposure.spotMeteringPoint.y=value
camera.exposure.manualShutterSpeed = value
camera.exposure.iso  = value
camera.exposure.manualAperture=value
```

I try to use `searchAndLock()` function for start focusing, exposure calculation, but after running this function status of my camera is still `Unlocked` rather `Searching`.

What can I do with this bug?
Which version of Qt I can install that doesn't has this bug?

I was success to fix bug of `SerialPort` by read this link:
[How to make QSerialPort from Qt5.13.1 work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58020663/how-to-make-qserialport-from-qt5-13-1-work)

Is there a way for fix this bug by me?

Qt Version: Qt 5.13.1 (MSVC 2017, 32 bit), 
Platform: Windows 10

Comment: _What_ code doesn't work? What does _not work_ mean? _What_ a bug? You have to clarify the queswtion and provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you expect to get an answer.

Comment: For example camera.searchAndLock() does not work.

Comment: You have to clarify what your _not work_ mean.

Comment: I try to use "searchAndLock()" function for start focusing, exposure calculation, but after running this function status of my camera is still "Unlocked" rather "Searching".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should check that your camera actually has any supported focus modes, and what these modes are:

```
console.debug("supported focus modes: " + focus.supportedFocusModes
                              + ", FocusManual: " + CameraFocus.FocusManual
                              + ", FocusHyperfocal: " + CameraFocus.FocusHyperfocal
                              + ", FocusInfinity: " + CameraFocus.FocusInfinity
                              + ", FocusAuto: " + CameraFocus.FocusAuto
                              + ", FocusContinuous: " + CameraFocus.FocusContinuous
                              + ", FocusMacro: " + CameraFocus.FocusMacro
                              )
```

By using the information provided by the results of this, you may set a focus mode that suits your camera hardware. There is a lot of different hardware out there, so please take that into account when writing your camera part of the app.